# AccessDenied on DynamoDB GSI Index

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I've wrote a `serverless.yml` to deploy some lambdas and I'm using GSI in a specific API.

If I run locally using serverless-offline, it's working but I'm facing an error when deploy the lambda:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::408462944160:assumed-role/telecom-integration-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/integration-dev-dialerStatistics 
is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:408462944160:table/integration-dialer-dev/index/other_dial_status-index
```

Here is how I've created serverless.yml

```
 iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: Allow
     Action:
      - dynamodb:Query
      - dynamodb:Scan
      - dynamodb:GetItem
      - dynamodb:PutItem
      - dynamodb:UpdateItem
      - dynamodb:DeleteItem 
    Resource:        
    - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DialerDynamoDbTable", "Arn" ] }


dialerStatistics:
  handler: integration/dialer.statistics
  description: Import data on dialer.
  memorySize: 256
  timeout: 30
  events:
    - http:
        path: dialer-statistics
        method: get
        cors: false
        private: false  


DialerDynamoDbTable:
  Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
  DeletionPolicy: ${self:provider.environment.DELETION_POLICY}
  # DeletionPolicy: Delete # Useful for recreating environment in dev
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      -
        AttributeName: "id"
        AttributeType: "S"
      -
        AttributeName: "dial_status"
        AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema:
      -
        AttributeName: "id"
        KeyType: "HASH"
    ProvisionedThroughput:
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DIALER_TABLE}  
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: "other_dial_status-index"
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "dial_status"
        KeyType: HASH
      Projection:
        ProjectionType: "ALL"
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: '20'
        WriteCapacityUnits: '20'
```

Probably it's missing some permission on iAmRoleStatements but I'm not sure what else should I do.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your IAM role does not cover the indexes. Try to add them in the role's ressources:

```
iamRoleStatements:
   - Effect: Allow
     Action:
       - dynamodb:Query
       - dynamodb:Scan
       - dynamodb:GetItem
       - dynamodb:PutItem
       - dynamodb:UpdateItem
       - dynamodb:DeleteItem 
     Resource:        
       - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DialerDynamoDbTable", "Arn" ] }
       - Fn::Join:
         - "/"
         -
           - { "Fn::GetAtt": ["DialerDynamoDbTable", "Arn" ] }
           - "index/*"
```

For reference, the Fn::Join will append `/index/*` to `DialerDynamoDbTable`'s ARN.

It worked locally because Serverless uses the "admin" IAM user you configured it with.

Comment: I got an error: "bad indentation of a sequence entry in file line 60, column 60:
     ... "DialerDynamoDbTable", "Arn" ] }/index/*  "

What is the correct syntax? Im super newbie on serverless

Comment: I updated the code with a correct indentation. My bad.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit tired. Values should be joined with the Fn::Join function. I updated (and tested) my code.

Comment: Deploying it! Is possible to check the result of Fn::Join? Just curious

Comment: CloudFormation will evaluate the join when deploying the stack. It's not serverless job to do it, so you won't be able to see it there. But you can see it in AWS IAM -> Roles. Also, you can guess what it will be by reading the documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176814/discussion-between-quentin-hayot-and-placplacboom).

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much, i own you a beer. ;D

Comment: @jah is it now ? :p

Comment: @quentinhayot No, the second dash has an indention on paste. Maybe thats SO formatting. Still thank you a lot ! :)

Answer (score 7):

```sh
Resource: 
    - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/${self:custom.myTable}
    - arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/${self:custom.myTable}/index/*
```

Answer (score 1):

for those in search of cloud formation

```
  PolicyDocument:
    Version: 2012-10-17
    Statement:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
        - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
      Resource: [!GetAtt DialerDynamoDbTable.Arn, !Join [ '/',[!GetAtt DialerDynamoDbTable.Arn,index/*]]]
```