# ARN for Query on DynamoDB index is not working

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I want to query an index in a DynamoDB table. When doing so I get the following error:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::XXX:assumed-role/bifr-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/bifr-dev-login is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:XXX:table/customers/index/email_index
```

After trying to fix it with the proposed configs in [AccessDenied on DynamoDB GSI Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537795/accessdenied-on-dynamodb-gsi-index) and AWS and DynamoDB permissions: "User is not authorized to access this resource" I came to the follwoing config, that still does not work. The same error persist. Maybe someone could help me with solving this problem.

### Table config:

```
resources: 
      Resources:
        customers: 
          Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
          Properties:
            TableName: customers
            AttributeDefinitions:
              - AttributeName: "id"
                AttributeType: S
              - AttributeName: "email"
                AttributeType: S
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: "id"
                KeyType: HASH
            BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
            GlobalSecondaryIndexes: 
            - IndexName: 'email_index'
              KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: 'email'
                KeyType: 'HASH'
              Projection: 
                ProjectionType: 'ALL'
```

### IAM Role config:

```
iamRoleStatements:
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - dynamodb:GetItem
    - dynamodb:UpdateItem
    - dynamodb:PutItem
    - dynamodb:Scan
  Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/*"
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - dynamodb:Query
  Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:250781267785:table/customers/index/email_index"
```

### NodeJS code for the query:

```
var res = await aws.QueryItems({
    TableName: tableName,

    IndexName: 'email_index',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#email = :email',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#email": "email"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":email": email
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the indentation. The `iamRoleStatements` must be a child of the `provider`.

Here my working config:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: us-east-1
  iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:GetItem
          - dynamodb:UpdateItem
          - dynamodb:PutItem
          - dynamodb:Scan
        Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/*"
      - Effect: Allow
        Action:
          - dynamodb:Query
        Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/customers/index/*"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazondynamodb.html#amazondynamodb-table

you need to add the ARN for the table to the dynamodb:Query IAM statement.

Comment: Isn't that what I did with: `Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:250781267785:table/customers/index/email_index"`

Comment: no, that's the ARN of the index. Which I believe you need also.